# $\mathbb{R}$, together with topology $\mathcal{T}=\{ U\subseteq \mathbb{R}:U^c \text{ is finite }\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathbb{R}_f$ be the set of real numbers, together with the topology $\mathcal{T}=\{ U\subseteq \mathbb{R}:U^c \text{ is finite }\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$

Find with proof the interior and closure of $[0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}_f$

It seems like only finite sets are closed, so how can I make a closed set, which contains $A$, which is also finite. So then it seems like the closure is $\mathbb{R}$. And similarly it seems like the interior has to be $\emptyset$ since any set contain in $A$ will have an infinite complement so can't be open.

My definition of interior is the union of all open sets contained in $A$. My definition of closure is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$.

I'm going to try and prove that $int(A)=\emptyset$ and $cl(A)=\mathbb{R}$

Suppose $U$ is an open set contained in $A$.

Then $U^c\subseteq (-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$, which is not finite. Thus there are no non trivial open sets contained in $A$. So $int(A)=\emptyset$ since it is the only open set which is a subset of $A$.

Suppose $V$ is a closed set containing $A$. Then $V^c$ is open, so $V$ must be finite. But if $V$ is finite it cannot contain $A$, since $A$ is not finite. So $cl(A)=\mathbb{R}$ since there are no other closed sets containing $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, with respect to this topology there is one and only one infinite closed set, which is $\mathbb R$. So, since $[0,1)$ is infinite, its closure is $\mathbb R$.

And the only open subset of $[0,1)$ is the empty set. That's so because if there was a non-empty open subset $A$ of $[0,1)$, then $A^\complement\supset[0,1)^\complement=(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$, which is impossible, since $A^\complement$ is finite. So, the interior of $[0,1)$ is the empty set.